# Execute a function for ten seconds and disable it for two seconds

Tags: unity

I have a particular function which I am calling in Update function.
For the first ten seconds, the function should get called in Update function, then it should get disabled for next two seconds, then again enable it for next ten seconds. This cycle should keep repeating? How can I execute it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alternatively, there is one-liner using modulus:

```
void Update()
{
    //if you want it loop from specific start time rather than from start of the game, 
    //subtract said time value from Time.time argument value
    if(Mathf.Repeat(Time.time, execDuration + sleepDuration) < execDuration)
        executeFunction();
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `Repeat()` and `%` (modulus)?  The documentation says _"this is similar to the modulo operator but it works with floating point numbers"_, but modulus works with floats...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yes and no - as far as I know in various languages the `%` operator often  act weirdly - either doesn't work with floating point numbers, gives unexpected or outright incorrect results for modulus operation in its math meaning (reflecting hardware nature of the operation on integers). `Repeat()` was chosen just as a safer option to avoid necessity of looking up exact implementation of `%` operator in C#/mono.

Comment: I thought every language implemented the IEEE 754 standard, but TIL [the standard's "modulo" definition is unintuitive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ieeeremainder(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) so almost no languages implement it.

Comment: It would be better if you implemented the comment over code as another code block and titled them accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tested the following code, but you will get the idea :

```
public float wakeUpDuration = 10.0f ;
public float sleepDuration = 2.0f;
private bool callFunction = true ;
private float time = 0 ;

void Update()
{
    time += Time.deltaTime;
    if( callFunction )
    {
         if( time >= wakeUpDuration )
         {
             callFunction = false;
             time = 0 ;
         }
         else
         {
             foo(); // Your function
         }
    }
    if( !callFunction && time >= sleepDuration )
    {
        callFunction = true;
        time = 0 ;
    }
}
```

Comment: That should only work if `deltaTime` is relatively short.  If the delta is longer than `sleepDuration` then this will fail.

Comment: if sleepDuration > Time.deltaTime, then, you don't need such system.

Comment: No.  Say deltaTime is 2.75 seconds.  You wil have 3 or 4 "active" calls then one "sleep" call, until the 50 second mark, when you should have 8 active calls in a row.  Also, in that scenario, the first sleep call comes at 11 seconds -- you reset time to 0 -- it should be set to 1.

Comment: In Unity, Time.deltaTime represents the elapsed time between the current frame of the game engine and the last frame (thus, I hope for the final user that Time.deltaTime will never be 2.75 seconds, ....). In **this** context, you may "miss" a call to the function or a "non"-call to the function, which is not an issue here IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a coroutine also. Something like

```
public class Comp : MonoBehaviour
{
  private bool _shouldCall;

  Start() 
  {
    StartCoroutine(UpdateShouldCall)
  }

  Update() 
  {
    if(_shouldCall)
        CallTheFunction();
  }

  IEnumerator UpdateShouldCall()
  {
    while(true) 
    {
        _shouldCall = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
        _shouldCall = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    }
  }

}
```